# $\lim\limits_{m\to 0}\dfrac{{}_1F_2\left(-\frac 12;\frac 12,\frac m2;x\right)}{\Gamma(m)}$

Tags: limits, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

What is the limit for following expression

$$f(x)=\lim_{m\to 0}\frac{{}_1F_2\left(-\dfrac 12;\dfrac 12,\dfrac m2;x\right)}{\Gamma(m)}\quad \text{with}\quad x\in\mathbb{R},$$

where ${}_1F_2$ is the hypergeometric series and $\Gamma$ the gamma function? Single values are

$$f(-1) \approx 1.69809, \qquad f(0)=0, \qquad f(1) \approx-2.36873$$

Comment: So it is ${}_1 F_2$ and not ${}_2 F_1$? Also, hypergeometric functions are usually not defined on the whole real line.

Comment: it is ${}_1F_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we write out the function with the [Pochhammer symbol](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pochhammer):

$$\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\,_1\text F_2\left(-\frac12;\frac12,\frac m2,x\right)}{\Gamma(m)}=\lim_{m\to0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-\frac12\right)_nx^n}{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(\frac m2\right)_n\Gamma(m)n!}$$

A limit [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+m-%3E0+pochhammer%28-1%2F2%2Cn%29%2F%28pochhammer%281%2F2%2Cn%29pochhammer%28m%2F2%2Cn%29gamma%28m%29n%21%29):

$$f(x)=\lim_{m\to0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-\frac12\right)_nx^n}{\left(\frac12\right)_n\left(\frac m2\right)_n\Gamma(m)n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2\left(-\frac12\right)_nx^n}{n!\Gamma(n)\left(\frac12\right)_n}=-2x\,_1\text F_2\left(\frac12;\frac32,2;x\right) $$

It is a [combination](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-2catalan+HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%2F2%7D%2C+%7B3%2F2%2C+2%7D%2C+catalan%5D) of [Struve L](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=StruveL) and [Bessel I functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=besselI):

$$\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\,_1\text F_2\left(-\frac12;\frac12,\frac m2,x\right)}{\Gamma(m)}=2\text I_1\left(2\sqrt x\right)\left(\pi x\text L_0\left(2\sqrt x\right)+\sqrt x\right)-2x\text I_0 \left(2\sqrt x\right) \left(\pi \text L_1 \left(2\sqrt x\right)+2\right)$$

When evaluating, [Bessel J](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=besselj) and [Struve H](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=struveh) appear because of the imaginary unit. Single values include

$$f(-1)=2\text J_1(2)(\pi\text H_0(2)-1)-2\text J_0(2)(\pi \text H_1(2)-2)= 1.69809097088030636354471441251561 \\f(1)=2\text I_1(2)(\pi\text L_0(2)+1)-2\text I_0(2)(\pi\text L_1(2)+2)= -2.36873010158184893306470337240… $$

Comment: Do you get the same values regardless of what phase of $-1$ you are using?

Comment: @Gary You look interested in this math problem. If you mean using $\sqrt{-1}\to -i$, then [yes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+BesselI%5B1%2C+-2+Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D+%28-Sqrt%5Bx%5D+%2B+x+Pi+StruveL%5B0%2C+-2+Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%29+-+2+BesselI%5B0%2C+-2+Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D+%282+x+%2B+x+Pi+StruveL%5B1%2C+-2+Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%29%2Cx%3D-1).